# Need help with ESXi Server from VMWare

Tags: vmware-esxi

I'm new to ESXi Server.

I need to build on a Laptop ASUS NX90JQ with a QuadCore, 8GB RAM and 2 500GB HDD the following scenario:
I need to implement multiple Windows Server 2008 R2 as Virtual Machines and have console access to them on the same machine (The ESXi Server).

Is there a tool like a Thin Software Client that i can install on the ESXi Server to Access to the Virtual machines without needing another machine.

This cenário would allow a trainer on trip to have a complete network on a single powerful laptop and use it as a workstation too.

If someone knows a possible solution to this i would become very grateful.

Vitor

Answer (score 1):

Is there any reason it has to be ESXi? You'd be much better off with [VMware Workstation](http://www.vmware.com/products/workstation/) in that scenario.

Regardless, it's important to note you wouldn't be able to run x64 machines under ESXi running as a virtual machine.

My recommendation is to fork out the cash for Workstation, or use another virtualization like virtualbox.

Comment: +1 for VirtualBox, unless you need VMWare compatibility for some reason.

Comment: Thanks, but i need to use Hiper-v on some of those machines, so i would like to install a solution without dual boot that could allow the user to have a workstation (Windows 7) that he uses to access the domain and multiple machines to give some training, running at the same time without a Windows 7 SO implemented on the physical machine that consumes too much resources

Comment: You're question is a bit contradictory. You want a laptop to run a virtualization technology without the overhead of a full OS install, but you want them to be able to access the console of the virtual machines. In order to access the console of the virtual machines, you need an OS running that will support console access. The best you could do is run a stripped down version of linux with just enough OS to run a virtualization platform.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to use ESXi, as you won't have console access to the VMs on that laptop. Instead pick up VMware Workstation (for a cost) or VMware Player (free, but can't do snapshots and stuff, which is probably something you'd want to do if running product demos) and run on top of Windows 7. Or you can use VMware Server (free) and run on top of a Windows 2008 Server, but that'd probably take more native resources than Windows 7.

Comment: you can't run multiple machines at the same time with vmware player...

Comment: true, true. Scratch the Player recommendation.

Comment: Thanks, but i need to use Hiper-v on some of those machines, so i would like to install a solution without dual boot that could allow the user to have a workstation (Windows 7) that he uses to access the domain and multiple machines to give some training, running at the same time without a Windows 7 SO implemented on the physical machine that consumes too much resources.

Comment: @JakeRobinson Since when can you not run multiple machines at the same time with VMware player? I'm running two machines *right now* in VMware Player version 3.0.1 on a Windows 7 host.

Answer (score 0):

What you want for this to work is VMware Workstation. This would allow you to run multiple server instances just like ESXi, but from within a Windows session, allowing you to access everything from the laptop itself.

Comment: Yes, but without the a windows 7 as the base of the physical machine to allow more resources

Comment: If i use WMware Workstation, i will need for example Windows 7 and that doesn't allow me to have Virtual Servers using Hiper-V.

Comment: Can i use a virtual machine on a VMWare Workstation that can use Hiper-V even if the OS of the physical machine doesn't support it like windows 7?

Comment: I believe so, but why not load Server 2008R2 on the laptop with Hyper-V enabled? Then load VMware Workstation. I've not tried this because I don't use Hyper-V, but it seems a plausible solution. This way you are not limited by Windows 7.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately there are no drivers for Windows Server 2008 to this laptop, only Windows 7, Windows Vista and Windows XP, and i would loose all the tools that Windows 7 Ultimate has, because this laptop is very good, it even has Bang & Olufsen Colmuns.

Answer (score 0):

As its been stated above you will probably have to use a type 2 hosted hypervisor for what you are describing, Virtualbox and VMware Workstation as good examples provided.

What you are asking about is running a type 1 bare-metal hypervisor, which does save you resources because you are not installing on top of a pre-existing OS, but you will have to remote into the VMs from another computer.  This may work if you want to tote the laptop, as a portable server, and then just log into the VMs from another laptop.

Comment: Exactly. But i was trying to access through the same machine, because this laptop is 5kg heavy and the trainer has to go around the world, so 2 laptops is not something nice to carry. But ok, it seems that at this moment i don't have other solution.